# Word for corrupt middlemen/landlords during the Roman era?

Tags: synonyms

I happen to know about this word, but presently it escapes my memory. Basically, I'm trying to communicate to someone about how does working in a large bureaucratic software company feels. The managers in those companies today are pretty much like these Roman overlords of the past who just made a living out of exploiting the poor farmers and taking advantage of the disconnect between them and the royalty.

Comment: internuncius, medium, intercessor, philantropus, interpolator, conciliator, interlocutor , interpres, and mediator. Any of these?

Comment: How about *publicani* =tax farmers?

Comment: Politician? :-)

Comment: blood sucker...

Comment: Actually, the word was `fedual lords` as in `the feudal system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't from the Roman era, but it sounds like you are talking about **feudal lords and vassals** - the vassals are the exploited farmers.

Comment: Indeed. The word was feudal lords as I'd read about the feudal system in history books in my childhood. I somehow confused that with the Romans!

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it difficult to look up words based on your definition, but I've managed to find a few that might fit.

> [**profiteer**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/profiteer) (*n.*)
> A person who [makes or seeks to make an excessive or unfair profit, especially illegally or in a black market]
>
> [**taskmaster**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/taskmaster) (*n.*)
> A person who imposes a harsh or onerous workload on someone.
>
> [**double-dealing**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/double-dealing) (*v.*)
> The practice of working to people’s disadvantage behind their backs (*a double-dealer*)
>
> <sub>Source: Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

You mention corruption, oppression, and general exploitation, and these fit pretty well with all that.

Answer (score -1):

Could the word you are looking for be ***plebeian***.

As [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plebs) makes clear the *plebs* were the ordinary citizens of Rome, as a whole.

The word got plenty of treatment in the news in the UK a year or two ago, when a Cabinet Minister -Andrew Mitchell- was alleged to have called some police officers protecting Downing Street *plebs*. The row went on for months.

Answer (score -1):

I immediately thought of "Slavedriver", which is a more negative form of "Slave Owner". It means that they drive their slaves very hard. It does not apply only to Roman times but there were many slave owners at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Latifundista - in the sense that it refers to a landlord, or landed gentry.

> A latifundium is large landed estate or ranch in ancient Rome typically worked by peasants or slaves.

Patrician

> Originally referred to a group of ruling class families in ancient Rome

Possibly also 'consul' or maybe even 'aristocrat'.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?